# Binding SelectedItem on DataGrid doesn't work

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid

This problem has been pestering me for the past few days. The window is a basic address entry, by querying the database and displaying the results.

User first enters the street (Bound to Query.Street), then city (Bound to Query.City) and then from the results list (DataGrid bound to QueryResults) selects the appropriate street.

Querying the DB is done in the PropertyChanged of Query object in the ViewModel and it works nicely. I bind the `ObservableCollection<Location> QueryResults` to DataGrid ItemsSource and when there is only one item left in QueryResults I assign it to `Location SelectedAddress` like this (`this` being the ViewModel):

```
this.PropertyChanged += (sender, e) =>
{
    switch (e.PropertyName)
    {
        case "QueryResults":
            // QueryResult contains only one result
            if (this.QueryResults?.Count == 1)
            {
                // select that result
                this.SelectedAddress = this.QueryResults.First();
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
};
```

I subscribe to this event in the ViewModel constructor.

`QueryResults` in the ViewModel:

```
internal ObservableCollection<Location> _queryResults = new ObservableCollection<Location>();
public ObservableCollection<Location> QueryResults
{
    get { return this._queryResults; }
    set
    {
        this._queryResults.Clear();
        if (value != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in value)
            {
                this._queryResults.Add(item);
            }
        }
        OnPropertyChanged("QueryResults");
    }
}
```

This is the `SelectedAddress` property:

```
internal Location _selectedAddress = new Location();

public Location SelectedAddress
{
    get { return this._selectedAddress; }
    set
    {
        this._selectedAddress = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("SelectedAddress");
    }
}
```

I then bind `this.SelectedAddress` to `SelectedItem` of the DataGrid, so that it would visually select it. DataGrid code:

```
<DataGrid Name="dgQueryResults" 
            MaxHeight="212.6" 
            RowHeaderWidth="0"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            CanUserAddRows="False"
            CanUserDeleteRows="False"
            CanUserReorderColumns="False"
            CanUserResizeRows="False"
            IsReadOnly="True"
            VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
            ItemsSource="{Binding QueryResults}" 
            SelectionMode="Single"
            SelectionUnit="FullRow"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedAddress, Mode=TwoWay}"
            SelectionChanged="dgQueryResults_SelectionChanged"
            >
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="LightGreen"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="LightGreen"/>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridCell}}">
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Binding="{Binding Street}" IsReadOnly="True">
            <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                <TextBlock Text="Street"/>
            </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Binding="{Binding City}" IsReadOnly="True">
            <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                <TextBlock Text="City"/>
            </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Binding="{Binding Municipality}" IsReadOnly="True">
            <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                <TextBlock Text="Municipality"/>
            </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

`dgQueryResults_SelectionChanged` is there only to `ScrollIntoView` the selected row.

`SelectedAddress` is also bound to a panel which displays the selected address and a description (this is a standalone property in the ViewModel, that gets copied into `SelectedAddress` when it changes) that the user can enter, so that user can double check that they selected the correct address:

```
<DockPanel>
    <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Top" Text="Selected address" FontWeight="DemiBold"/>
    <DockPanel DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
        <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Top" Text="Floor, extra description:"/>
        <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Text="{Binding Description}"/>
    </DockPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" DataContext="{Binding SelectedAddress}">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="Street" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Street}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="House number" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding HouseNumber}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="City" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding City}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="Municipality" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Municipality}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</DockPanel>
```

**The problem** is that when there is only one item left in the DataGrid (or equally in `QueryResults`), I want to select it automatically (I check for this when `QueryResults` changes and if it contains only one item assign it to `SelectedAddress`), so that the DataGrid would update its selected item. This does not happen. `SelectedAddress` property in the ViewModel changes, the `OnPropertyChanged("SelectedAddress");` is called, however DataGrid does not select the only row remaining, nor does the DockPanel update. However when I click on a row in the DataGrid, the `SelectedAddress` is updated and the DockPanel updates instantly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:** Resetting the windows `DataContext` when `SelectedAddress` changes works, but its a workaround that I'd rather not use.

Comment: The way you `Clear` and re-`Add` your observable collection worries me. It means that after the clear, the `SelectedItem` will be out of sync with the available items. Sometimes a `Binding` decides to disable updates when it can't produce proper results within a few attempts.

Comment: Ok, I'll check into it and report back. I'll rewrite it so that it wont assign a new `ObservableCollection` to `QueryResults` but will add/remove items to/from it.

Comment: @grek40 Still doesn't work :/

Comment: Can you check, whether the collection- and propertychanges happen on the UI thread (something like `Thread.CurrentThread == Dispatcher.Thread`)?

Comment: Yes, both the collection change and the `SelectedAddress` changes occur on the UI thread. I compared the `Window`s thread and the current thread in the PropertyChange events and in the setter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

Even though I was properly raising the `PropertyChanged` event, I did not indicate that my `ViewModel` implements the interface `INotifyPropertyChanged`, so that is why the change did not reflect on the UI.